# Dissecting text from CSV using PowerShell

Tags: powershell, csv, split

I have scoured the web for the following solution to my problem... I currently have text in a csv format that I need to break apart into several columns as shown below

```
Task ID,Task Name,Project                   
2,2 - CR04AW212 Warehouse,2 Crown Castle International : 001586 2013 ALU Phase 3 Sprint Crown : 001623 CR04AW212 ALU Sprint                 
10,10 - CR04AW090 Tower Punch,24 Alcatel Lucent : 001713 2013 ALU AAV : 001752 CR04AW090 ALU AAV
```

And I need to translate\breakdown into several columns pulling apart text as shown below

```
Task ID,Task Name,Customer ID,Customer Name,Parent Project ID,Parent Project Name,Child Project ID,Child Project Name
2,CR04AW212 Warehouse,2,Crown Castle International,001586,2013 ALU Phase 3 Sprint Crown 001623,CR04AW212 ALU Sprint
10,CR04AW090 Tower Punch,24,Alcatel Lucent,001713,2013 ALU AAV,001752,CR04AW090 ALU AAV
```

The Task ID number is found repeated again in the Task Name. I would like to strip that number from name as shown in the second image

The Project column essentially contains all the data needed to break into 6 columns. I believe there has to be a way to programmatically select the text. I will go into it one bit at a time. The "Customer ID" column should contain the number before the first space in the "Project column" This could consist of a single digit or double digit number. Irregardless, that number should always exist before the first empty space in "Project". Being the obvious novice i was able to accomplish it with the -split parameter

@{Name="Customer ID";Expression={($_.Project -split ' ')[0]}}.

Now I must select the following text "Customer Name" that will always exists after the first space and before the ":".

This example persists 2 more times. The "Parent Project ID" and "Child Project ID" are fixed 6 digit numbers. The text following each ID is represented as the name of that project.

And here is where my google searches have been exhausted

I apologize for not uploading images, I just registered and StackOverflow won't allow me to until i am reputable enough :)

EDIT: How do I quit after the first match?

```
Add-Member -PassThru NoteProperty 'Task Name' -Value ($_.'Task Name' -replace '\d+ - ')
```

At the Moment if I had

```
1,1 - JA03MR008 - Civil,9 New Tech Construction Corp. : 001583 2013 Panhandle : 001810 JA03MR008"
```

it results in stripping all matches when I would like to remove the first match in "Task name"

> Task ID: 1
>   Task Name           : JA03MRCivil
>   Customer ID         : 9
>   Customer Name       : New Tech Construction Corp.
>   Parent Project ID   : 001583
>   Parent Project Name : 2013 Panhandle
>   Child Project ID    : 001810
>   Child Project Name  : JA03MR008

I took a crash course in REGEX for this and this is what I believe worked best for my purpose. See the code below. It seems to work great. Is there a caveat to using it this way? Thanks in advance

```
Add-Member -PassThru NoteProperty 'Task Name' -Value ($_.'Task Name' -replace '^([^-]*) - ')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are probably many ways to skin this cat, I would suggest using regex to process Project property of input object:

```
@"
Task ID,Task Name,Project
2,2 - CR04AW212 Warehouse,2 Crown Castle International : 001586 2013 ALU Phase 3 Sprint Crown : 001623 CR04AW212 ALU Sprint
10,10 - CR04AW090 Tower Punch,24 Alcatel Lucent : 001713 2013 ALU AAV : 001752 CR04AW090 ALU AAV
"@ | ConvertFrom-Csv | ForEach-Object {
    if ($_.Project -match '(\d+) ([^:]+) : (\d+) ([^:]+) (: (\d+) (.*))?') {
        $_ | select 'Task ID' |
            Add-Member -PassThru NoteProperty 'Task Name' -Value ($_.'Task Name' -replace '\d+ - ') |
            Add-Member -PassThru NoteProperty 'Customer ID' -Value $Matches[1]                      |
            Add-Member -PassThru NoteProperty 'Customer Name' -Value $Matches[2]                    |
            Add-Member -PassThru NoteProperty 'Parent Project ID' -Value $Matches[3]                |
            Add-Member -PassThru NoteProperty 'Parent Project Name' -Value $Matches[4]              |
            Add-Member -PassThru NoteProperty 'Child Project ID' -Value $Matches[6]                 |
            Add-Member -PassThru NoteProperty 'Child Project Name' -Value $Matches[7]

    }
}
```

This would probably require some polishing here and there. E.g. you could use select-object + hashtables instead of Add-Member. It would be sooo much easier in v3, but I assume this has to be v2 compatible, thus no v3 code used.

**EDIT:**
Updated the code with code that is able to handle option when there is no child project, new regex:

```
 '(\d+) ([^:]+) : (\d+) ([^:]+) (: (\d+) (.*))?'
```

it's making last two pieces: `: (\d+)` and `(.*)` optional: `(pattern)?`
$Matches[5] will be either blank, or will contain optional group, so you need to change indexes for child project properties to 6 and 7.

Comment: BartekB - nice answer.  What are the V3 features you speak of?  Haven't looked at Server2012/Win8 yet.

Comment: `[PSCustomObject]@{}` that gives nice objects with preserved order of properties, `Add-Member -NotePropertyMembers ([ordered]@{})` that would simplify this code and give same benefit of keeping properties in correct order...

Comment: This is excellent BartekB. Now I just need to apply it to 5,600 rows in Sample.csv. I will post back when I can figure out how to do it. Be right back :)

Comment: BartekB... I took a closer look into the results displayed by your code. I was wondering how I can have blank values for "Child Project ID" and "Child Project Name" in the event I have a line such as

Comment: @BartekB... I took a closer look into the results displayed by your code. I was wondering how I can have blank values for "Child Project ID" and "Child Project Name" in the event I have a line such as

2,2 - CR04AW212 Warehouse,2 Crown Castle International : 001586 2013 ALU Phase 3 Sprint Crown

In this row for example I don't have a second semicolon and ideally I would need for result output to be blank as shown below

2,CR04AW212 Warehouse,2,Crown Castle International,001586,2013 ALU Phase 3 Sprint Crown,,

Comment: I've updated answer with optional match around child project properties, please test it, my limited tests worked fine.

Comment: Excellent again sir. This completes the script.. You're help is greatly appreciated